# The correct regular expression to search for multiple occurrences

Tags: c++, regex

I have this source text:

```
{ff0000}Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.{8b00ff}Ut enim {FFFFFF}ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.{0000ff}Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
```

The task is to divide this text into 4 occurrences of a regular expression

The results should look like this:

1. `{ff0000}Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.`
2. `{8b00ff}Ut enim`
3. `{FFFFFF}ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.`
4. `{0000ff}Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.`

I have compiled a regular expression that looks for HEX colors, but I can't limit the search to the next occurrence

Regular expression: `\{[a-zA-Z0-9]{6}\}`

I tried: `\{[a-zA-Z0-9]{6}\}.* | (\{[a-zA-Z0-9]{6}\}{1}).* | ((\{[a-zA-Z0-9]{6}\}{1}).*){1}`

In all three cases after the addition `.*` all other HEX characters are no longer perceived by the regular expression and are perceived as `.*`
The question is to somehow limit each following regular expression to the occurrence of the next HEX color

Comment: What language are you using? Most provide a way to use a regular expression as a delimiter when splitting up a string. E.g. `re.split()` in Python, `preg_split()` in PHP.

Comment: How the expression works will also depend on the language you are using and the code you use.

Comment: I use C++ and I think I can find such a function, but I would like to divide it exactly inside the expression itself and then sort them out regex_search

Comment: You can get the 4 matches by eg [`\{[A-Za-z\d]{6}\}[^}{]*`](https://regex101.com/r/8pLDUp/1) (using a [negated class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) after the hex part for matching characters that are not `{` `}`)

Comment: Based on the positions of the matches, you can determine the substrings. Assuming, you've got matches starting at indices `a[0]`, ..., `a[k]` in a string `s` of length `n`, `std::string_view(s.c_str() + a[i-1], a[i] - a[i-1])` for i = 1, ..., k are matches, plus `std::string_view(s.c_str() + a[k], n-a[k])`

Answer (score 1):

For matching characters that are not `{` use a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated).

```
\{[A-Za-z\d]{6}\}[^{]*
```

[See this demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/8pLDUp/2)

If this is inside nested braces, add `}` to the class for [not skipping over](https://regex101.com/r/VrD9V5/1).

Comment: I think it is possible to use only { as the character of the beginning of the line, since each subsequent line begins with {
that is, [^}{]* can be replaced with [^{]*

[Example](https://regex101.com/r/dZOfSI/1)

Comment: @Shersula Thank you, yes I think too! I have edited the answer accordingly :)

Answer (score 1):

Just use the positions of the matches to determine the relevant substrings. Every substring starts with the occurance of one of the patterns and ends either at the end of the input string or the next match of the pattern, whatever comes first.

```
std::vector<std::string> FindMatches(std::string_view const input)
{
    std::regex reg("\\{[a-zA-Z0-9]{6}\\}");
    constexpr size_t MatchLength = 8;


    std::vector<std::string> result;

    std::match_results<std::string_view::const_iterator> match;
    if (std::regex_search(input.begin(), input.end(), match, reg))
    {
        auto partStart = input.begin() + match.position();
        while (std::regex_search(partStart + MatchLength, input.end(), match, reg))
        {
            auto partEnd = partStart + (MatchLength + match.position());
            result.emplace_back(partStart, partEnd);
            partStart = partEnd;
        }
        result.emplace_back(partStart, input.end());
    }

    return result;
}

int main()
{
    using namespace std::literals::string_view_literals;

    auto const haysack = "{ff0000}Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.{8b00ff}Ut enim {FFFFFF}ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.{0000ff}Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."sv;

    size_t index = 1;

    for (auto& part : FindMatches(haysack))
    {
        std::cout << index << ". " << part << '\n';
        ++index;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I did this initially before creating this theme. But in the end I decided that it was not worth leaving such an option, I think the implementation through regular expressions looks more correct, although your decision is also correct, thank you